# GStreamer Tee : x264enc + jpegenc -> deadlock?

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, mjpeg, tee

I have the following GStreamer commands working :

1°) streaming 2 MJPEG streams over TCP :

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! deinterlace mode=1 ! videorate ! videoscale ! tee name=tp \
\
tp. ! queue ! video/x-raw, framerate=10/1, width=960, height=540 ! jpegenc quality=40 ! multipartmux ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=8093 \
\
tp. ! queue ! video/x-raw, framerate=15/1, width=960, height=540 ! jpegenc quality=40 ! multipartmux ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=8096
```

2°) streaming 2 MP4 streams over TCP :

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! deinterlace mode=1 ! videorate ! videoscale ! tee name=tp \
\
tp. ! queue ! video/x-raw, framerate=10/1, width=960, height=540 ! x264enc bitrate=1000 ! mpegtsmux ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=8093 \
\
tp. ! queue ! video/x-raw, framerate=15/1, width=960, height=540 ! x264enc bitrate=1000 ! mpegtsmux ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=8096
```

But this one doesn't (trying to stream 1 MJPEG stream and 1 MP4 stream over TCP) :

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! deinterlace mode=1 ! videorate ! videoscale ! tee name=tp \
\
tp. ! queue ! video/x-raw, framerate=10/1, width=960, height=540 ! jpegenc quality=40 ! multipartmux ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=8093 \
\
tp. ! queue ! video/x-raw, framerate=15/1, width=960, height=540 ! x264enc bitrate=1000 ! mpegtsmux ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=8096
```

The command line says :

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Redistribute latency...
```

Which sounds fine, but I'm unable the play the streams in VLC (it's working with the 1st command line).

The only change is that I replaced, for only one of the streams :

```
jpegenc quality=40 ! multipartmux
```

by :

```
x264enc bitrate=1000 ! mpegtsmux
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here :
http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Pipeline-Freezes-When-Adding-In-Tee-With-x264enc-td4301890.html

Using "x264enc tune=zerolatency" made it working !